# Event filter with query could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003

Tags: tfs

In my SCVMM server, the following error is logged in events.

> Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

Try this workaround from Microsoft. It's actually a good one, and comes with a "real" explanation of the problem.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545227 (For Win7 and Server 2008 R2)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950375  (For Vista and Server 2008)

In summary, this is a leftover WMI registration from the ISO creation process that can be safely removed.

For Windows 7, make a .vbs file with the following and execute it from an elevated command prompt:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\subscription")

Set obj1 = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from __eventfilter where name='BVTFilter' and query='SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ""Win32_Processor"" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99'")

For Each obj1elem in obj1

set obj2set = obj1elem.Associators_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

set obj3set = obj1elem.References_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

For each obj2 in obj2set

WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

WScript.echo obj2.GetObjectText_

obj2.Delete_

next

For each obj3 in obj3set

WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

WScript.echo obj3.GetObjectText_

obj3.Delete_

next

WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

WScript.echo obj1elem.GetObjectText_

obj1elem.Delete_

Next
```